# Inheritance Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

Given is the following table structure, which I can't change:

```
Table A {
    idA auto_increment primary key
    [... some values...]
}

Table B {
    idB auto_increment primary key
    idA foreign key referencing Table A
    [... some values...]
}

Table C {
    idC auto_increment primary key
    idA foreign key referencing Table A
    [... some values...]
}
```

I want to map these tables to an abstract super class and two sub classes as follows:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class A {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    private int aID;

}

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (name = "idA")
public class B extends A {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int bID;

}

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (name = "idA")
public class C extends A {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int cID;

}
```

It seems that these annotations are not correct and hibernate cannot handle the two IDs in the sub classes.

Assuming that the given table structure can't be changed, what is the best way to map the table structure to a class structure?

Comment: trying to smash entity-inheritance onto a legacy database is a road to madness.  Use a MappedSuperclass to model the common properties.

Comment: Is it true that every B and C row "is an" A row (implying inheritance)? or is it more correct to say that each B and C row is related to an A row (implying a OneToMany relationship between entities and not inheritance).

Comment: @Charlie class A represents a Person, class B represents an InternalEmployee, class C represents an ExternalEmployee.